# Compare top record against Top record -1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was asked to create a report comparing all clients most recent order and their previous order, and then compare and return only those who placed orders with a higher amount as their next order. (I really hope this makes sense)

The order history table is laid out in such a way as each customer has an Order number that is sequential to that Customer (E.G. If a customer places 5 orders, then their top order number is 5, which should make this easier.) So for a customer with 5 orders, I would want to compare order #'s 4 and 5, and then only return this customer if Order #5 was for a higher Dollar amount.

The Order amount is stored in a different table, but they are linked by a guid reference (ID).

```
SELECT TOP 1 CO.OrderNumber
                        ,COD.Amount
                FROM cust_OrderDetail COD
                    INNER JOIN dbo.cust_Order CO ON Cod.cust_OrderID = CO.ID 
                    INNER JOIN Customer c ON CO.Customer = c.ID
                WHERE COD.Amount > (SELECT COD1.Amount
                                        FROM cust_OrderDetail COD1
                                        INNER JOIN dbo.cust_Order CO1 ON Cod1.cust_OrderID = CO1.ID 
                                            WHERE CO1.Ordernumber = (This is where I fall apart)
```

I hope this makes sense. I fall apart right there at the end. I know how to link in all the other details and everything else that is needed here. It is just this one comparison that kicks my teeth in.

Comment: "Order number that is sequential to that Customer" this stmt is not matching the query you have wrote. while joining COD and CO you need CustomerID and OrderID both if the OrderID is sequential for each Customer. you can join just based on OrderID only if the orderID is given in sequence across all customers. so which one is true?

Comment: Disregard this, I am going a completely different direction with the report based on using a Date filter instead. Thank you for the reply Ahup Shah, I wish I could upvote you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query returns Customer and CustomerOrder info correctly

**Approach:** Get your top 2 records per customer in CTE and then compare the Topmost record with the previous one.

```
WITH Top2 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
SELECT c.ID, CO.OrderNumber ,COD.Amount,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY c.ID, CO.OrderNumber DESC) Rnk
FROM cust_OrderDetail COD
 INNER JOIN dbo.cust_Order CO ON Cod.cust_OrderID = CO.ID 
INNER JOIN Customer c ON CO.Customer = c.ID
    ) T WHERE Rnk <= 2)


SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM Top2 Where Rnk = 1) T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Top2 Where Rnk = 2) T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
AND T1.Amount > T2.amount
```